# Show variable in meta tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, tags, meta

I have a div which is like this:

```
            <div id="beskrivelse" class="description html_content" itemprop="description">
                {{description}}
            </div>
```

The content `{{description}}` is made in the backend.

How can I make it so that this content will be shown in my meta here:

```
            <meta property="og:description" content=" HERE "/>
```

I get a syntax error if I write:

```
            <meta property="og:description" content=" {{description}} "/>
```

Is ther a simple way to do it? Maybe put it in a variable of some sort?

There is no way for me to change this in the backend as I am using a closed system.
I want what I have written in my `{{description}}` to be shown in the meta tag.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what templating system are you using? smarty? laravel?

Comment: What is the syntax error message? Your code seems valid for all template engines.

Comment: Im using the tictail shop system. To be honest i do not know what language the system is written in. I can't find anything in their docs either.

Comment: Im using the built-in themes in tictails manager. I'm using the "Reconnaissance" theme.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript you can achieve this.

```
<script language="javascript">
var descval = document.getElementById('beskrivelse').innerHTML;
var paras = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
for (i = 0; i < paras.length; i++) {
 var test = paras[i].getAttribute('property');
 if(test == "og:description")
 {
   paras[i].content = descval;
 }
}
</script>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/vTtn2/)

Using Devloper Tool you can check the meta tag new content.

Comment: How do i implement this? :)

This is the entire template: http://pastebin.com/22TM5ED1

Comment: Testing this in jsfiddle doesnt do anything by the way

Comment: copy the above code and keep it in your project before "</body>" tag.